# How to refer a struct array all fields

Tags: c, sorting

I am using a struct array:

```c
struct person
{
    char name[100];
    char address[100];
    char IDnumber[20];
    int  age;
}; 

struct person student[10];
```

to store data which has 4 fields. Now I want to sort them alphabetically by "name" field.

How to refer student array to do the swap operation to swap all fields?

```c
char temp;

for(int r=0;r<k-1;r++) {
       for(int s=r+1;r<k;r++) {

          if(strcmp(student[r], student[s]) > 0) {
            strcpy(temp,student[r]);
            strcpy(student[r],student[s]);
            strcpy(student[s],temp);
          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: You _must_ go back to your C book. This is elementary. However, you use the `.` (dot), for example `if (strcmp(student[r].name, student[s].name)>0)`

Answer (score 1):

By treating struct variable as any other normal variable.

```
      if(strcmp(student[r].name, student[s].name) > 0) {
        struct person temp = student [r];
        student[r] = student[s];
        student[s] = temp;
      }
```

Comment: I modified code as below but still , it does not give the expected result ? Names are not sorted alphabetically

Comment: @CgsGunasekara Please show what you have modified and what result it is giving and what is expected result.

Comment: Names are not sorted alphabetically

Comment: char temp;

            for(int r=0;r<k-1;r++) {
                   for(int s=r+1;r<k;r++) {

                      if(strcmp(student[r].name, student[s].name) > 0) {
                        
                         struct person temp =student[r];
                       
                        student[r]=student[s];
                       
                        student[s]= temp;
                      }


                   }


               }

Comment: @CgsGunasekara Names will not be sorted but structure array will be sorted according to name as you expected.

Comment: but the struct student does  not sort by names

Comment: Please share complete code, otherwise it is difficult to debug